# What dimension mean in context of convolutional layer?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

This table describe [neural network architecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02304) and I don't understand what exactly `dim` (dimension?) column means for convolution and residual layers.

[image: network architecture]

Is this just multiplication of dimensions of layer? Like `4x8x64 -> 2048`?
Then how such network can preserve constant `dim` after all these conv layers with stride 2x2 (which cut in half 2 dims)?

Also is this correct Stack Exchange site for such questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When the number of channels increases, we use a single convolutional layer with filter size of 5x5 and a stride of 2x2. Thus, the the frequency dimension is kept constant in all convolution layers."

It looks like this is paper-specific notation. And frequency dimension is dimension of frequency multiplied by number of filters. So if we have input with shape `batch_size x frames x frequency x conv_filters` then `frequency x filters` is `dim` mentioned in table.

I hope that I understood it correctly.